# Referenced cell turns black if many cells are selected

Tags: vba, excel

I have these sheets `Sheet1` and another which is `Sheet2`.

`Sheet1` gets its values (including color of the cell) from `Sheet2`.

I have this block of code to check for the active cell color in `Sheet2` and then change the color of the same cell in `Sheet1`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Interior.Color = 5296274 Then
    Worksheets("ALL BRANDS").Range(Target.Address(False, False)).Interior.Color = 5296274
Else
    Worksheets("ALL BRANDS").Range(Target.Address(False, False)).Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Range(Target.Address(False, False)).Interior.Color
End If 
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Interior.Color = 5296274 Then
    Worksheets("ALL BRANDS").Range(Target.Address(False, False)).Interior.Color = 5296274
Else
    Worksheets("ALL BRANDS").Range(Target.Address(False, False)).Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Range(Target.Address(False, False)).Interior.Color
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is when I select multiple cells at a time in `Sheet2` 
[image: SelectCell]

it colors the referenced cell in `Sheet1` to
[image: Black]

Comment: `Range.Interior.Color` does not return an array... while you can write it for multiple cells, read will fail if not all cells have the same color...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect the `Interior.Color` property of each cell individually.

When a `Range` object consists of multiple cells, a few properties (like `Value` and `Formula`) will return an array of values.  Many properties, including `Interior.Color`, will not.  In the case of `Interior.Color`, if ALL the cells in the range have the same background color, you will get the correct value.  If even one cell has a different color, the property cannot give you a single correct answer, and simply returns 0 (black).

As a side note, your If statement isn't doing anything useful as written.  I'll assume you want to copy any occurring color for the sample below.  If you only want to copy that certain shade of green, keep your If but drop the Else.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim c As Range
  With Worksheets("ALL BRANDS")
    For Each c In Target
      .Range(c.Address).Interior.Color = c.Interior.Color
    Next c
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim c As Range
  With Worksheets("ALL BRANDS")
    For Each c In Target
      .Range(c.Address).Interior.Color = c.Interior.Color
    Next c
  End With
End Sub
```

Really, you should move that code into a function and call it from each event instead of rewriting and maintaining the code in multiple places.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this! As for the else, I was trying to set the cell of the "ALL BRANDS" as the one with the current sheet

Comment: Hmm - that was my original answer to the question, but the OP said it didn't work - said it still set everything to black.  Oh well, as long as it works for them now.